# Quick view of data on mouse hover in laravel angularjs

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have requirement where I wanted to show a quick view of page. So the condition is when I mouse hover over any menu the page should be shown with the data from the backend api. I have like 12 menus and all of them are some kind of reports and these all reports have messy queries. So way I am doing it now is when user login for the first time I made 12 api request and I only get 5 records of each menu and I store the each api request result in to localstorage and when user again reloads the it doesnt make the api request for any screen but for 15 minutes and if user reloads the page after 15 minutes all the 12 request will be hit again.

But one my friend suggested that what if we create a trigger and we write all the queries in the trigger and we run the trigger before 15 minute call and the result of these query should store in a new table and when after 15 minutes when system again make api hit you only make one request and get the data from this table and show the result this way you only have to make one call. Then I think its a good idea but the issue here is that the queries are very messay and some of them run in a loop and the loop query result is stored in array which later becomes the final result of the api call and each api call of 12 have like 20 columns values in result so I am stuck on how I am going to store the 20 columns values in a single columns and how I will run the query in a loop.

Or is there any better idea to do this. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Stop thinking based on requests. Create those reports on a time based schedule and only refer to the last version created in your html document.

Comment: its not about request its about showing things very fast if 12 server request will be made then it will take time to show the final result

Comment: That is exactly what I referred to. You need to prepare the results _prior_ to receiving the request.

Comment: how can I do that I tried my ways but its not working. The only way I think is trigger but it seems to failing

Comment: "many ways" and "its not working" is nothing we can respond to. You need to ask _precise_ questions. I suggest you read a few tutorials about getting started with background processes ("cron jobs") in a web environment.

Comment: I am creating a mysql trigger but I dont think it will work. Is there any other way I can store the result before making the actual request? And I can't run cron job because the result is per user and if I use cron job then it will on each 15 minutes

Comment: I don't see what a mysql trigger has to do with this and I already answered to "any other way" in my last comment. It seems you do not really read the comments you receive, but only glance at them...

Comment: I cant run a cron job every 15 minutes where it will execute the query of thousands of users. I am going to use a trriger how else I am going to store the data before actual request

Comment: Then you need to decouple. Something like "gray logging" or "elastic search" or an elk might be a start. But for certain you cannot wait for a user to hover or click and _then_ run queries lasting 15 minutes and expect the result to show.